# Help with rooting lollipop, Verizon branded phone

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, verizon

I want to root my HTC One M7, but it is branded by Verizon. When I got to:

`Settings>About>Software information`, I have:

[image: Screenshot 1]

When I click More, I have:

[image: Screenshot 2]

I had root from the app Kingoroot (yes with the O), took Security update from Verizon, and lost root. Now Kingoroot always fails. Kingroot (without the o) works SOMETIMES, but then my phone reboots either when I try to do something root-related, or after about one minute. I have tried several other One tap and One click apps/programs, but the ydo not work. Here is a list of what I have tried:

Kingroot (PC & APK)
Kingoroot (APK, for some reason I get a 500 error when trying to get the PC version)
Framaroot (Says not vulnerable)
z4root (Just installs inapropriate apps)
iRoot
Weaksauce
Wondershare TunesGo
Towelroot

Rumrunner fails with either "Such dumb issues you have" or "F* it".
   1. Why is this happening

2. How do I fix it

I do not have $25 for Sunshine

I really want my phone rooted. I do not care if it is by one click, or by somehow getting a custom recovery and ROM. I would rather the recovery and rom, specifically TWRP and Cyanogenmod.

Thanks for any help. I will provide more specific information if requested.

PS. I forgot to add:
I have access to ADB, fastboot, and can even set up adb to use by localhost
   From computer:
    adb tcpip 5555

And from the phone itself (I use Material Terminal Emulator):
    adb connect localhost:5555

Comment: Is your bootloader unlocked?

Comment: @esQmo It's Verizon, of course it's locked

Comment: I think the update you download had a patch that closed the security holes used by one-click rooting apps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple of things to get your phone rooted, not temp root.

There is a step-by-step [guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-root-and-S-Off-the-HTC-One-M7-Internation/) on Instructable. Just follow it.

If the above doesn't work, try [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-one/help/root-htc-one-m7-5-0-2-t3074744).